# unable to pipe output of grep to hdfs file system

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run below command:

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://meldstg/db/bus_svcs/landing/gobblin/prep/edm_gw_test/AssignedCharge/* | \
grep -w  aLDMAssignedProduct_0_200_400 | \
hadoop fs -put - hdfs://meldstg/user/ebdpbuss/prelanding/test/test3.txt
```

but it is creating an empty `test3.txt` file, is there any way I can pipe output of `grep` to a HDFS file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try running the command `hadoop fs -cat hdfs://meldstg/db/bus_svcs/landing/gobblin/prep/edm_gw_test/AssignedCharge/* | grep -w aLDMAssignedProduct_0_200_400` and see if there is actually some output there?

Comment: possibility is grep doesn't match to any pattern